# How to create the index file for connection to the database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am creating a form using HTML, PHP and MySQL. I need help trying to link all the 3 together and send the data to the database.

Have researched quite a bit online and I see we have to create some kind of index file but because I am a beginner at all of this I am finding it hard to understand how to proceed. I have created the form with HTML, PHP and Excel (as the database) but I need to shift that to MySQL.

```
<?php

$error = '';
$RequestorName = '';
$SESAID = '';
$Q2C = '';
$Line = '';
$ExpectedDate = '';
$ReasonList = '';
$Description = '';
$checkbox = '';

function clean_text($string)
{
 $string = trim($string);
 $string = stripslashes($string);
 $string = htmlspecialchars($string);
 return $string;
}

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
 if(empty($_POST["RequestorName"]))
 {
  $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Please Enter Requestor Name</label> 
  </p>';
 }
 else
 {
  $RequestorName = clean_text($_POST["RequestorName"]);
 }

 if(empty($_POST["SESAID"]))
 {
  $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Please Enter SESAID</label></p>';
 }
 else
 {
  $SESAID = clean_text($_POST["SESAID"]);
 }

 if(empty($_POST["Q2C"]))
 {
  $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Please Enter Q2C Number</label> 
  </p>';
 }
 else
 {
  $Q2C = clean_text($_POST["Q2C"]);
 }

 if(empty($_POST["Line"]))
 {
  $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Please Enter Line Number</label> 
  </p>';
 }
 else
 {
  $Line = clean_text($_POST["Line"]);
 }

 if(empty($_POST["ExpectedDate"]))
 {
  $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Expected Date is required</label> 
  </p>';
 }
 else
 {
  $ExpectedDate = clean_text($_POST["ExpectedDate"]);
 }

 if(!isset($_POST["ReasonList"]))
 {
  $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Please select a reason</label> 
  </p>';
 }
 else
 {
  $ReasonList = clean_text($_POST["ReasonList"]);
 }

 if(empty($_POST["Description"]))
 {
  $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Description is required</label> 
  </p>';
 }
 else
 {
  $Description = clean_text($_POST["Description"]);
 }

 if(!isset($_POST["checkbox"]))
 {
  $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Please upload all the files</label> 
  </p>';
 }

 if($error == '')
 {
  $file_open = fopen("Revision_Tracker.csv", "a");
  $no_rows = count(file("Revision_tracker.csv"));
  if($no_rows > 1)
  {
   $no_rows = ($no_rows - 1) + 1;
  }
  $form_data = array(
   'sr_no'  => $no_rows,
   'RequestorName' => $RequestorName,
   'SESAID' => $SESAID,
   'Q2C'  => $Q2C,
   'Line'  => $Line,
   'ExpectedDate' => $ExpectedDate,
   'ReasonList'  => $ReasonList,  
   'Description' => $Description
  );
  fputcsv($file_open, $form_data);
  $error = '<label class="text-success">Thank you!</label>';
  $RequestorName = '';
  $SESAID = '';
  $Q2C = '';
  $Line = '';
  $ExpectedDate = '';
  $ReasonList = '';
  $Description = '';
}
}
```

```
<input type="text" name="RequestorName" placeholder="Enter Name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $RequestorName; ?>" />
     </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <label>SESA ID of Requestor</label>
      <input type="text" name="SESAID" placeholder="Enter SESA ID" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $SESAID; ?>" 
      </div>


On clicking Submit the values entered on the form will move to Excel. This operation works for me. I want to know how to implement it with MySQL. Everything I read is just going over my head.
```

Comment: I have only posted a portion of the HTML file as I didn't think anything would change there.

Comment: First you need to create your database, create the tables required, define the fields and datatypes required within the table(s). Then you need to determine what method you are going to use to access your database (https://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.database.vendors.php) then follow some examples of accessing the database (https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php).

Comment: @jeff Thank you. I have used phpmyadmin to create the database and tables required and defined the fields. 
With regards to how to access it I am unable to understand how to change the php code I have written to cater to database change.

Comment: Here is how to connect to a database with PHP https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Comment: How to run a database query https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php